# CSV import button discontinued. How can i import CSV into Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, importerror, import-from-excel

I have migrated my app to Heroku. However, i wish to use Parse.com app as a backup backend environment for a while longer.
This requires me to import CSV data into my parse.com class.
However, Parse removed the import CSV feature from the Dashboard.
Can anyone provide a tool that i can use to import CSV data into my parse.com app ?

Answer (score 0):

These tools are helpful to import and export ;

1. NoSQLBooster for mongoDB
2. MongoDB Compass
3. Robo3T